# What is the eucalyptus-like tree?

Tags: identification, trees, tree-care

The white peeling bark looks like eucalytpous, but the leaves look like Lophostemon confertus (Brisbane box).

Found in urban setting in Inglewood, California.

Thanks[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it appears to be a eucalyptus. It's hard to tell without a better view of the leaves and "fruit", but to me it looks like a Corymbia maculata (spotted gum).

Here's some detail about the Corymbia maculata from CalPoly San Luis Obispo https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/corymbia-maculata

Answer (score 0):

It might be Lophostemon confertus.
The leaves are folded down the middle which excludes Eucalyptus and most Corymbia.
It does look like an Australian tree, if so from the warmer subtropical parts which I dont know well.

Comment: middle folded leaves exclude Eucalyptus? Are you sure? I live in australia, where every bloody gum tree has middle folded leaves. The tree in the picture thoug, does look like what we call a White gum, or similar.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_gum

Comment: I mean to say the Eucalyptus leaves are flat, not folded along the central vein like in the photo.